# Can I say "I'm making power to get out from my bed."?

Tags: phrase-request, american-english

When you wake up lazy and don't want to rise up, can you say:

> "I'm making power to get out from my bed."?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Henri! I'd say "I'm **gathering my strength** to get **off** the bed" - but wait for native speakers' opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be funny if I say I am making power to get out of bed as it will normally mean that I am  generating or making electricity to get out of bed.

There are many verbs that can be used in the sentence.  For example, gather (up), muster (up), summon (up) my strength/energy.  As I am not a native speaker and I don't know what the native speaker says in this situation, I will go for the easy verb, that is, gather.

I am gathering (up) my strength/energy to get out of bed.

Answer (score 6):

No, that's not something a native speaker would say. Some options would be:

> I'm gathering the strength to get out of bed.
>
> I'm marshaling the will to get out of bed.
>
> I'm mustering the energy to get out of bed.

Note that the correct preposition here is "of", not "from". Also, saying "my bed" isn't wrong, but you could just say "bed", since it's more or less implied that you are sleeping in your bed.

Comment: Not a bad set of options, but [***psyching myself up***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m+psyching+myself+up%22) is far more common than ***marshaling the will*** if it's about being in the right *mental* state rather than being physically strong enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would say: I have to force myself to get out of bed.