# out of vehicle vs out from vehicle

Tags: prepositions

Please see which of the following two clauses is correct/better?

> 1) The cow came **out of** the truck.
>   2) The cow came **out from** the truck.

Comment: Could someone transfer this to ELL, which would probably be closed for being a duplicate?

Comment: @BlessedGeek: since ELL site graduation, you can vote to close with "belongs on ELL" as a predefined reason :)

Comment: Related: [Can I say “I'm making power to get out from my bed.”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62512/can-i-say-im-making-power-to-get-out-from-my-bed)

Comment: Both are correct, but "out of the truck" is easier to say and therefore more likely to be used.

Comment: Both convey the same meaning, but "out of" is normally used in America.  "out from" is the preposition form that my native-German-speaking relatives usually use.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct as well as understandable. As an American I feel that `out of <location>` feels more natural.

However, you can use `out from <preposition> <location>`. For example:

> Come out **from** **under** that rock!
>
> The suspect came out **from** **behind** the tree with his hands held up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with number 1.

"From" is generally used with places larger than trucks. :-)

E.G. He came from Chicago.